# Links not clickable in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on this site http://zap3d.com/ and I have a problem: With Internet Explorer (IE) I can't click the two links (Upload and Download) but with Chrome and Firefox I can.

Here is my CSS for Upload button

```html
<a href="/User/Upload/" class="button_big upload_button"></a>
```

```css
.upload_button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 47px;
    bottom: 28px;
    width: 237px;
    height: 41px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some versions of Internet Explorer may not register clicks on elements that have a transparent background, and no content within. In these cases, set your element's opacity to zero:

```css
.upload_button {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

You'll get the same *invisible element* effect, while maintaining cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: @HarshitTailor: Please consider green-checking this answer if it served your purpose. More details here on how to do so - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow